# PyBind11: How to implement Vector of Shared Pointers of Classes with Inheritence? Unable to load a custom holder type from a default-holder instance

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have a base class in c++ that looks like:

```cpp
class EdgeAttributePipelineStep {
public:
    virtual void setAttributes(Edge& edge) = 0;
};
```

And then some classes that inherit from this class:

```cpp
class FuelCostStep : public EdgeAttributePipelineStep {
public:
    FuelCostStep(float fuelCostPerTonne)
        : m_FuelCostPerTonne(fuelCostPerTonne) {};
    void setAttributes(Edge& edge);

private:
    float m_FuelCostPerTonne;
};

class HireCostStep : public EdgeAttributePipelineStep {
public:
    HireCostStep(float hireCostPerDay) : m_HireCostPerHour(hireCostPerDay/24) {};
    void setAttributes(Edge &edge);
private:
    float m_HireCostPerHour;
};
```

And then finally, a class that accepts a vector of the base class in its constructor:

```cpp
class EdgeAttributePipeline {
public:
    EdgeAttributePipeline(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<EdgeAttributePipelineStep>> steps);

private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<EdgeAttributePipelineStep>> m_steps;
};
```

I want to be able to create the pipeline class in python like:

```py
pipeline = EdgeAttributePipeline([
    FuelCostStep(10),
    HireCostStep(10)
])
```

And I attempted some python bindings using PyBind11 to do this:

```cpp
#include "edge_attributes.h"
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>

PYBIND11_MODULE(WeatherRouting, m)
{
    py::class_<EdgeAttributePipelineStep>(m, "EdgeAttribtuePipelineStep");
    // I tried both using std::shared_ptr
    py::class_<FuelCostStep, std::shared_ptr<FuelCostStep>>(m, "FuelCostStep")
        .def(py::init<double>());
    // And not using std::shared_ptr
    py::class_<HireCostStep, EdgeAttributePipelineStep>(m, "HireCostStep")
        .def(py::init<double>());
    py::class_<EdgeAttributePipeline>(m, "EdgeAttributePipeline")
        .def(py::init<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<EdgeAttributePipelineStep>>>());
}
```

However both of these attempts resulted in the same error:

```py
>>> EdgeAttributePipeline([FuelCostStep(10)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Unable to load a custom holder type from a default-holder instance
>>> EdgeAttributePipeline([HireCostStep(10)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Unable to load a custom holder type from a default-holder instance
```

I also had a look at making a [trampoline class](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html#combining-virtual-functions-and-inheritance):

```cpp
class PyEdgeAttributePipelineStep : public EdgeAttributePipelineStep {
public:
    using EdgeAttributePipelineStep::EdgeAttributePipelineStep;
};
```

And modifying the pybind code:

```cpp
    py::class_<EdgeAttributePipelineStep, PyEdgeAttributePipelineStep, std::shared_ptr<EdgeAttributePipelineStep>>(m, "EdgeAttribtuePipelineStep");
    py::class_<FuelCostStep, EdgeAttributePipelineStep>(m, "FuelCostStep")
        .def(py::init<double>());
```

However this now makes a new error when ran in python:

```
ImportError: generic_type: type "FuelCostStep" does not have a non-default holder type while its base "EdgeAttributePipelineStep" does
```

I am a bit stuck trying to implement this. How do I get this code to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the same holder for all related types (so the base, child, grandchild, etc). You forgot to set a shared_ptr holder for `HireCostStep`.

FWIW, I use the smart_holder branch of pybind11 and it removes all of this holder related pain. I don't understand why it isn't in master by now.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it fixed my issues formatting them like: `py::class_<HireCostStep, EdgeAttributePipelineStep, std::shared_ptr<HireCostStep>>` and then for the base class, `py::class_<EdgeAttributePipelineStep, std::shared_ptr<EdgeAttributePipelineStep>>`